# Can PyCharm have multiple conda environment variables for the same project

Tags: python, pycharm

There are many discussions on how to use conda environment variables in PyCharm projects. These discussions, however, often assume that for each PyCharm project only one conda environment variable is used. Then here is my question: is it possible to have multiple conda enviroment variables for the same project?  I give the following example to make my point much clearer:

```
pycharm_project_name
      abc.py       (use conda environment variable: TensorFlow)
      def.py       (use conda environment variable: Caffe)
```

In this example, the PyCharm project has two python scripts with each depending on its own environment variable. In this case, how could I set the PyCharm project in a proper way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to run the scripts within a particular environment, this is easily acomplished using different [run configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html) for the different scripts. This will allow you to select the configuration from the dropdown and click play to run it.

[image: Run configuration menu]

The run configuration dialog has a "Python interpreter" option, where you can select the environment to run in.

Unfortunately, there is no simple way to configure different environments for the other popular way of running scripts, which is to right click on them and select the run option from there.